# How do I best do balanced quoting with Perl's Regexp::Grammars?

Tags: regex, perl, grammar, regexp-grammars

Using Damian Conway's [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Grammars-1.002/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm), I'm trying to match different balanced quoting (`'foo'`, `"foo"`, but not `'foo"`) mechanisms -- such as parens, quotes, double quotes, and double dollars. This is the code I'm currently using.

```
<token: pair>        \'<literal>\'|\"<literal>\"|\$\$<literal>\$\$
<token: literal>    [\S]+
```

This generally works fine and allows me to say something like:

```
<rule: quote>            QUOTE <.as>? <pair>
```

My question is how do I reform the output, to exclude the needles notation for the `pair` token?

```
{
  '' => 'QUOTE AS \',\'',
  'quote' => {
               '' => 'QUOTE AS \',\'',
               'pair' => {
                           'literal' => ',',
                           '' => '\',\''
                         }
             }
},
```

Here, there is obviously no desire to have `pair` in between, quote, and the `literal` value of it. Is there a better way to match `'foo'`, `"foo"`, and `$$foo$$`, and maybe sometimes `( foo )` without each time creating a needless `pair` token? Can I preprocess-out that token or fold it into the above? Or, write a better construct entirely that eliminates the need for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Damian, the answer was actually in the [*"Manual result distillation"*](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Grammars-1.002/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm#Manual_result_distillation) part of the docs

```
The correct answer is to tell your <pair> token
to pass the result of each <literal> subrule through as its own
result, using the MATCH=
alias (see: "Manual result distillation" in the module documentation)  like so:

   <token: pair>        \'<MATCH=literal>\' | \"<MATCH=literal>\" |
\$\$<MATCH=literal>\$\$
```

Here is what the docs say:

> Regexp::Grammars also offers full manual control over the distillation process. If you use the reserved word MATCH as the alias for a subrule call [...] Note that, in this second case, even though  and  are captured to the result-hash, they are not returned, because the MATCH alias overrides the normal "return the result-hash" semantics and returns only what its associated subrule (i.e. ) produces.

Answer (score 0):

Use another great module by Damian, [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Balanced).

Comment: how do I integrate that in the rest of my Regexp::Grammars?